# GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 0 -- IIS -- Windows 10 -- PHP V 7+

Tags: php, curl, iis, drupal

Enabled app insights on php project, it is working on host machine. However, during running the same code on local box getting following error: [seems some IIS config issue or update not sure]

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see what went wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information. (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in ....\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 186

and

Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file. in ....\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 56

Trace:

[trace while running an application from IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjYWS.png)

Comment: Could you please share which curl version you are using? its more likely PHP or curl issue, not iis. you could refer this GitHub issue links: [link1](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1723) ,[link2](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1456) ,[link3](https://github.com/bunq/sdk_php/issues/7)

Comment: curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL, however same code is working on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

check the plugins and look through the debug.log file in wp-content and most likely it is a plugin that is causing this issue.  I found that Mailjet causes this issue when unconfigured.  Simply activate the plugins found in the error log and this will help solve it.  The Microsoft version of cURL in PHP will throw the error and the Linux variant will not.

Comment: The OP seems to be using Drupal, not WordPress.